# PhpStorm removing tabs/spaces on every save

Tags: phpstorm

I just updated to PhpStorm 2016 and I noticed that suddenly every time I press <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> to save the file it removes the spaces/tabs that I pressed to continue writing after testing this bit of code.

Pleas help, this is very annoying for me, since I save my file after every line of code.

Here is a screenshot when I'm about to save, so after hitting <kbd>Ctrl + S</kbd> the text cursor will move all the way to the left, deleting all spaces & tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to disable `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Remove trailing spaces on:` option.

[image]

*(NOTE: in older IDE versions you may have just a drop down box and have to select the `None` option there)*

---

**P.S.** Please note that if you have `.editorconfig` files in your project then corresponding setting from there (`trim_trailing_whitespace`) will overwrite such IDE setting. It is expected as it's the whole nature of such files.

If you do not like that then either edit your `.editorconfig` file accordingly (https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig/wiki/EditorConfig-Properties#current-universal-properties -- i.e. have `trim_trailing_whitespace = false`) or disable such support in the IDE (`Settings/Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Enable EditorConfig support`)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed 2016.3, and thanks for the fast answer. It works perfectly now!

Comment: Didn't help me. even on VSCode i have same problem. and no, there is no .editorconfig in my project.

Comment: @Sabrina `.editorconfig` file may be in another location (any folder up .. or even user profile/home folder) -- depends on how each editor handles that. Other than that (not editor config or the editor settings): this could be some tool that watches your files (e.g. linter/code style fixer/transpiler etc)

Answer (score 18):

I recently experienced the behavior that trailing spaces got removed everywhere although the option `Settings/Preferences > Editor > General > Strip trailing spaces on Save` was set to `Modified Lines`. Setting the option to `None` didn't help nigher.

The reason for that was, that I had installed the JetBrains IDE plugin [EditorConfig](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7294-editorconfig). In the root of my (PHP-) project I had a 
**.editorconfig** file with the setting `trim_trailing_whitespace = true`. Setting that to false, fixed the issue.

Comment: Version 2020.3 doesn't seem to have the option `None`. As mentioned by @LarS updating **.editorconfig** to set it as false did the trick for me. That line was under `[*]` as true and under `[*.md]` as false.

Answer (score 2):

PhpStorm 2021.2.3

Just Settings/Preferences > Editor > General

- scroll down to On Save