# Trailing whitespace gets deleted by Webstorm. How to stop it?

Tags: git, typescript, webstorm

I want to make a PR for phaser.io however when i want to commit the file there seems to be changes in all the empty block comment lines. 
Since there are actually whitespaces in the original file i tried to deactivate the "Strip trailing whitespaces" option in Webstorm but it did not change a thing.

[image: original file]
[image: original file]

Anyone of you know how to prevent Webstorm from doing this? I haven't found anything on google yet.

EDIT: I changed the git screenshot to a clean one without new line changes.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I have edited the original question, since I am now sure that Webstorm just deletes those whitespaces in the block comment's empty lines.

Comment: When you deactivated the "strip trailing whitespace" option, did you reset the file to its original state?

Comment: yes i reverted it

Comment: BTW looking at the diff, there seems to be more changes that just this trailing whitespace removal highlighted in red, probably newlines are also changed (LF <-> CRLF), check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3920650/245966

Comment: you are right. i have tried around with the different newlines too. did not fix it though

Comment: I am not sure, but guess that webstorm and phpstorm works similar in this aspect, you may check the answers at https://stackoverflow.com/q/40962197/880188 ...

Comment: ... as I can see there is a [.editorconfig](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/blob/master/.editorconfig) file, make sure to check my answer there too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50688530/880188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People on the [Jetbrains boards](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205803079-Configure-editor-to-remove-whitespaces-in-blank-lines) are talking about this feature. It sounds like settings at a language level can override the general setting: ie if strip whitespace is turned on in TypeScript (??), that will take precedence over the general setting.

(Disclaimer: Haven't tried it myself)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I tried to do this: 
Default Settings >> Editor >> Code Style >> Typescript >> Tabs and Indents (tab) >> "Keep Indents on Empty Lines"

and also this: 
'Always keep trailing space on caret line'

Both did not change anything.